# The vector A is a linear combination of vector B and vector C if c =?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A= i+cj$

$B= i+2j+k$

$C= 3i+6j+3k$

Can you help me out? I don't know what else to do.
Thanks.

Comment: $\def\i{\hat i} \def\j{\hat j} \def\k{\hat k}$
*Hint:*

If $\vec a$ is a linear combination of $\vec b$  and $\vec c$ then there are constants $p, q$ such $\vec a = p\vec b + q\vec c$. Write out that equation and examine the implications for the coefficients of each of $\i, \j, \k$.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **doing** the calculation?  Saying that "vector A is a linear combination of vectors B and C" means that there exist numbers, x and y, such that A= xB+ yC.  Here, that means that i+ cj= x(i+ 2j+ k)+ y(3i+ 6j+ 3k)= (x+3y)i+ (2x+ 6y)k.  That, in turn, means that 1= x+ 3y, c= x+3y, and 0= 2x+ 6y.   Solve 2x+ 6y= 0 and x+ 3y= 1 for x and y- except that 2x+ 3y= 0 s the same as x+ 3y= 0 so that x+ 3y= 1 **can't** be true!  There is no such c.

Answer (score 0):

We have the equation system

$$r+3s=1$$

$$2r+6s=c$$

$$r+3s=0$$

The first and the third equation contradict each other, so there is no $c$, such that $A$ can be represented by $A=rB+sC$